# Trying to delete a vector index in a map

Tags: c++, maps

So I am trying to delete a certain index element in a vector within a map without removing the key just a certain index element.

```
using dictionary_type = map<unsigned, vector<char>>;
dictionary_type words;
```

that is the map i am using it is stored with 0-number of lines in a book and the char is the character at each position. Than I pull a text document read it in then search for similar characters with that text document and the book.

```
for (const auto& pair : words)
{
    // run an outer for to search through the message
    for (auto c = 0; c < message.size(); ++c )
    {
        // run and inner for to look at the second element of the map
        for (size_t i = 0   ; i < pair.second.size(); ++i)
        {
            // compare them to see if they're the same
            if (pair.second[i] == message[c])
            {  
                out << pair.first << " " << i << " " << endl;
                words.erase(pair.second[i]);
                // Trying to just delete the character at that index element            
                // once the character is found break out and search for the next
                break;
            } // end if

        } // end most inner for

    } // end second for
    // this makes it so the outside for wont repeat
    break;
} // end range for
```

Comment: That did nothing to help me, it still doesn't delete the element...

Comment: I assume there is a particular reason you are making use of `vector<char>` instead of `string`?

Comment: because I want to be able to find the characters later based on there line number and there offset from the left. Line number being the key and the vector index being the offset from the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand of your question, it boils down to:

> How do I remove characters from `vector<char> A` that matches characters in `vector<char> B`?

**New Solution**

After clarifications from the comments, I propose this new solution.

```
void removeMessage(dictionary_type& words, vector<char> const& message)
{
    for_each(begin(words), end(words), [message](auto& keypair)
    {
        for(auto const& charIter : message)
        {
            auto const& findIter = find(begin(keypair.second), end(keypair.second), charIter);

            if(findIter != end(keypair.second))
            {
                keypair.second.erase(findIter);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It performs the following:

1. Iterates over each dictionary entry
2. For each entry, iterates over the `message`
3. For each character in `message`, removes the first instance of that character in the current entry.

An example is show below ([see it running here](http://ideone.com/nGzqbg)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
using dictionary_type = map<unsigned, vector<char>>;

void removeMessage(dictionary_type& words, vector<char> const& message)
{
    for_each(begin(words), end(words), [message](auto& keypair)
    {
        for(auto const& charIter : message)
        {
            auto const& findIter = find(begin(keypair.second), end(keypair.second), charIter);

            if(findIter != end(keypair.second))
            {
                keypair.second.erase(findIter);
            }
        }
    });
}

void printMessage(vector<char> const& message)
{
    for(auto const& iter : message)
    {
        cout << iter;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    dictionary_type words;

    words.insert(std::make_pair(0, vector<char>{ 't', 'e', 's', 't' }));
    words.insert(std::make_pair(1, vector<char>{ 't', 't', 'o', 'o', 'r', 'r', 'n', 'n' }));

    printMessage(words[0]);
    printMessage(words[1]);

    cout << "\nRemoving 'torn'\n" << endl;

    removeMessage(words, vector<char>{ 't', 'o', 'r', 'n' });

    printMessage(words[0]);
    printMessage(words[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs

```
test
ttoorrnn

Removing 'torn'

est
torn
```

**Old Solution**

Here is one solution:

```
void removeMessage(dictionary_type& words, vector<char> const& message)
{
    for_each(begin(words), end(words), [&message](auto& keypair)
    {
        keypair.second.erase(remove_if(begin(keypair.second), end(keypair.second), [&message](auto& charIter) { 
            return (find(begin(message), end(message), charIter) != end(message));
        }), end(keypair.second));
    });
}
```

[See it running here](http://ideone.com/73UBhU)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I guess i should've been more clear and given an example with it so for example if the message is 'torn' and the other vector is for example 't', 't' ,'o', 'o', 'r' , 'r', 'n', 'n' I want to just remove the first t then the first o and the first r and the first n

Comment: @MemeLord See my updated answer and let me know if it helps at all.